# Disadvantages of view having direct reference to Manager(s), if following MVVM pattern?

Tags: android, mvvm, software-design, clean-architecture

I am following MVVM architectural pattern and if I access UserManager directly in Activity, would it be breaking the MVVM architectural pattern? What are the pros and cons of doing it?(in terms of scalability and testability)

Answer (score 0):

MVVM usually involves a component that holds your

1. Model / Data Class,
2. `View`(can be via `ViewBinding`) like an
3. `Activity` & a
4. `ViewModel`.

For example:
You will call a method for your data via the `ViewModel`, in this instance `UserManager`,
process it there (say inside a Coroutine) & expose the result via a `LiveData` / `Flow<T>`,
& use that data with your relevant `View`.

Check this link for more info.:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mvvm-model-view-viewmodel-architecture-pattern-in-android/